# How to Remove duplicate values from join query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi ever one how can i remove the duplicate records from this join statement.

```
SELECT  std_info.Reg_no, std_info.std_name, tut_fee.fee_month, class.class_name 
FROM std_info 
  INNER JOIN tut_fee on std_info.Reg_no=tut_fee.Reg_no 
  INNER JOIN promot on std_info.Reg_no=promot.Reg_no 
  INNER JOIN class on class.class_id=promot.class_id
WHERE std_info.Reg_no not in (SELECT Reg_no 
                              FROM tut_fee 
                              WHERE tut_fee.fee_month=3
                                AND tut_fee.fee_year=2014)
```

It give the result

```
 Reg_no     std_name    fee_month   class_name

 1. A01      name1         1           2nd
 2. A01      name1         2           2nd
 3. A02      name2         1           3rd
 4. A02      name2         2           3rd
```

Thanks For all.

Comment: I don't see any duplicates!

Comment: The Name1 and Name2 is repeating twice and want show  to like      A01 name1  2nd                                                     A02 name2  3rd          this for replay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I created the temporary table in database, name Fee_temp and then insert the record given by the query. And then make partition using Row_Number function.And delete all the record that is listed more than ones. Like give below.

```
   insert into Fee_temp SELECT   std_info.Reg_no,std_info.std_name,tut_fee.fee_month,class.class_name FROM
std_info Left  JOIN tut_fee on std_info.Reg_no=tut_fee.Reg_no Left JOIN promot on  std_info.Reg_no=promot.Reg_no Left JOIN
class on class.class_id=promot.class_id
WHERE std_info.Reg_no not in (select  Reg_no FROM tut_fee where  tut_fee.fee_month=3   and tut_fee.fee_year=2014)
 SELECT * from Fee_temp
  With A as
 (
 select Fee_temp.Reg_no,Fee_temp.std_name,Fee_temp.fee_month,Fee_temp.class_name,ROW_NUMBER() 
 OVER (Partition by Reg_no ORDER BY Fee_temp.std_name) As Number from Fee_temp
)
DELETE FROM A WHERE Number>1
SELECT * FROM Fee_temp
```

Answer (score 0):

the  dublicat Come  from the column "tut_fee.fee_month,"